# On screen keyboard is not typing - windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, on-screen-keyboard

Almost after 6 months I was using my personal laptop (Lenovo ideapad 320) running on windows 10. I can see that most of the keys are not working. Since it is password enabled i cant login to the system. Then I tried with on screen keyboard to type my password, which is also not working properly. I can hear the type sound but it is not typing, Most of the keys are not working there too. What could be the reason behind?

Comment: Faulty built-in keyboard may be the issue. Connect an external USP keyboard and see if that works. If it does, that is likely the issue so you can talk with a hardware computer repair shop or check warranty and call the location you purchased to see what your options are. Otherwise, just use an externally connected keyboard.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks. will try that.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT External USB keyboard also not working.